# Task does not contain a definition for Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to overcome the error below?
I have follow below tutorial but I get the red line that state that does not contain definition of `Content`.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVvJX4CoLUY

```
private void UploadFile_Cliked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
        "\"file\"",
        $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://192.168.137.1/pic/";
    var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
    RemotePathLabel.Text = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

[image]

> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the error but any idea to solve it?

I have add this *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* package but still fail

Comment: You need to `await` that.

Comment: missing an `await`, `var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(.....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the event handler async and then await functions that return Task derived results as you would have ended up with the same problem when calling `ReadAsStringAsync`

```
private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

private async void UploadFile_Cliked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
        "\"file\"",
        $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");        

    var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://192.168.137.1/pic/";
    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
    RemotePathLabel.Text = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Note that event handlers are an exception to the rule where `async void` are allowed

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)