# Cancelling PayPal subscription using HTTPClient returns "Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Tags: c#, paypal, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to cancel PayPal subscription(s) using `HttpClient`

This is my code

```
public void cancelPayPalAsync()
{
    var token = getToken();
    var subid = "I-XXXXXXXXX";

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subid + "/cancel"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);

            request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"reason\": \"Not satisfied with the service\"\n}");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns

```
Id = 1379, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? Practical examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Make your method `async` and then
`var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`
`var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` something like that.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewE, I'm getting the following when trying this: `Task<HttpResponseMessage> does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' ....?`

Comment: `request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"reason\": \"Not satisfied with the service\"\n}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102545/task-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-content